# How to properly link boost with cmake

Tags: boost, cmake

The root directory of boost ($ENV{BOOST_ROOT}) is

> C:\Boost\boost_1_64_0

All compiled libraries (.dll, .lib) are in

> C:\Boost\boost_1_64_0\lib64-msvc-14.1

They have both boost_xxx and libboost_xxx.

My cmake file is

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}") 
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}/lib64-msvc-14.1")

message("${BOOST_ROOT}")
message("${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}")
message("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")

if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB) 
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
endif()

find_package(Boost 1.64.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem program_options REQUIRED)
```

And the output is

> C:\Boost\boost_1_64_0
>
> C:\Boost\boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.1
>
> C:/Boost/boost_1_64_0
>
> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1842 (message):
>   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.64.0
>
> Boost include path: C:/Boost/boost_1_64_0
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>       boost_system
>       boost_filesystem
>       boost_program_options
> ```
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
>   to the   directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the
>   location of   Boost. Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:78 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:84 (message):   Boost not found

Could someone help please? I have spent hours on this but couldn't figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: Setting *BOOST_DEBUG* is exactly for debugging such cases. Do that and show the resulted log.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what CMake version do you use? Recently a regression fix was included into [3.8.1 release](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-3-8-1-available-for-download/) -- it was about backslashes in `BOOST_ROOT`.

Secondly, you don't need to specify anything else ('cept maybe the `BOOST_ROOT`) if you are using official prebuilt Windows binaries -- `FindBoost.cmake` would try to find them as well. (Unfortunately I can't recall since what version.)

**Never** do `set(BOOST_ROOT...)` in your `CMakeLists.txt` -- just pass this parameter to `cmake` run via `-D` option. A better way is the following:

```
if(NOT DEFINED BOOST_ROOT AND NOT "${ENV{BOOST_ROOT}" STREQUAL "")
    set(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}")
endif()
```

Use imported targets to link w/ needed Boost libraries and to modify compile/linker flags per taget. Please avoid to modify "global" compiler/linker options -- i.e. use corresponding [`target_xxx`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html) commands instead of `add_definitions` & etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to load boost with CMake (working with Linux and Windows) :

```
set(BoostPath "${DefaultBoostPath}" CACHE PATH "Path to Boost")
message(STATUS "Path to Boost: ${BoostPath}")
set(BOOST_ROOT "${BoostPath}")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.57.0" "1.57" "1.58.0" "1.58" "1.59.0" "1.59" "1.60.0" "1.60" "1.61.0" "1.61" "1.62.0" "1.62" "1.63.0" "1.63" "1.64.0" "1.64")
find_package(Boost ${RequiredBoostVersion} REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${RequiredBoostComponents})
mark_as_advanced(FORCE Boost_DIR)
set(BoostVersion "${Boost_MAJOR_VERSION}.${Boost_MINOR_VERSION}.${Boost_SUBMINOR_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Boost version: ${BoostVersion}")
if(CompilerName STREQUAL "gcc")
    set(System_LIBRARIES ${System_LIBRARIES} pthread rt)
endif()
```

You can see I have to add some versions of Boost because my version of CMake doesn't know last versions.
What's your CMake version ? Maybe it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your headers?  I don't think it found the include directory (which is necessary for this to be successful).

Search for [FindBoost.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html) in your cmake installation directory, there are lots of useful things in there for troubleshooting.

using `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` can help you figure out which paths are searched and what the filenames of the libraries are searched.  You can specify the include directory (directory where folder `boost` is stored) with `set(Boost_INCLUDEDIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/inc)`, though what I just showed is one of the places that FindBoost.cmake searches.

Also, you don't need `set(BOOST_ROOT "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}")`.  FindBoost.cmake does that for you if you don't set `${BOOST_ROOT}`.

Note that if you just downloaded boost, extracted the archive to `${BOOST_ROOT}` and compiled with `b2`, then all of your files are in `${BOOST_ROOT}/stage`. This is also a good place for them to reside.  If you manually copy files somewhere else, then FindBoost may have some troubles finding them.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way of including `boost` in `CMake` is:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.9 FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
add_executable(executable-name main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable-name ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```